# RESET java card applet when power loss during transaction

Tags: transactions, reset, javacard, apdu

I am new Java card development and I want to know how to handle transactions when power is lost during a transaction.  I want to know is there way to reset internally when power is lost or remove java card from card terminal. In my Java card applet I unsuccessfully tried:

- `JCSystem.beginTransaction();`
- `JCSystem.commitTransaction();`
- `Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic();`

Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks Sajith

Comment: How is it not working? And are you sure you want to use `arrayCopyNonAtomic` within a transaction (doesn't it defeat the purpose of that transaction)?

Comment: You are creating a lot of (valid) questions that are perfectly explained in the venerable book [Java Card Technology for Smart Cards](http://books.google.nl/books/about/Java_Card_Technology_for_Smart_Cards.html?id=4WDj4H6pT50C&redir_esc=y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within transactions writes to persistent memory such as EEPROM or flash are handled atomically. That is: as if all the writes to persistent memory are part of one big action.

To create an atomic copy you need to use `Util.arrayCopy()` instead of `Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic()`. There may also be other actions that can take part of atomicity. If actions that change persistent memory do **not** take part in an atomic transaction then the Java Card API will explicitly document those actions.

As indicated before, there is no method to reset a Java Card. Instead you can use `JCSystem.abortTransaction()`.